# How to send data from a component which is calling another component angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i have a problem, i have a component called `customers.component`

Here is the `customers.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer',
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css']
})

export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  customers: any;

  constructor(private titleService: Title) {
      this.titleService.setTitle(this.title);
      this.getCostumers();
   }
```

In the html of `customers.component` view i am calling another component called `details-customers.component` through a for looping inside of the array `customers`

```
<div id="listas" class="listas">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 fila_lista" *ngFor="let customer of customers">
        <app-details-customer></app-details-customer>
    </div>
</div>
```

The think that i want to do is send the variable customer which is the current variable of the actual position of the loop, To do something like this in my another component view `details-customers.component.html`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12 auto_mrg">
        <span>{{customer.name_owner}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12 auto_mrg ">
        <span>Tel: +{{customer.country_p.phone_code}} {{customer.phone}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 auto_mrg ">
        <span>{{customer.country_p.country_name}}, {{customer.city_p.city_name}} - {{customer.state_p.state_name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In other words, is to send the actual variable of the loop to the component that i am calling...

There is a way to do this?, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using property binding: https://angular.io/guide/property-binding

*customers.component.html:*

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 fila_lista" *ngFor="let customer of customers">
    <app-details-customer [customer]="customer"></app-details-customer>
</div>
```

*details-customer.component.ts:*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-details-customer',
  templateUrl: './details-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details-customer.component.css']
})

export class DetailsCustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() customer: any;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You needed use **@Input() customer: ClassName** in component details-customer

And And call this object like this **<app-details-customer [customer]="customer">**